# Referencing an algorithm written in Algorithm2e using Cleveref prints the word "Line+Number" instead of "Algorithm+Number"

Tags: pdftex, cleveref, algorithm2e

I am using the package `algorithm2e` to write some algorithms. However, when I reference a specific algorithm using `cleveref`, I get [**Line 1**] instead of [**Algorithm 1**]. Is there anyway to let `cleveref` detect the algorithm environment and give it the correct label-name?

Here is a minimal example:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,makeidx]{amsbook}
   \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
   \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
   \begin{document}
   \chapter{First chapter}
   \section{First section}
   \begin{center}
       \begin{algorithm}[H] \label{label-for-algorithm-1}
         code
       \caption{Algorithm}
       \end{algorithm}
   \end{center}
   \section{Second section}
   (See \Cref{label-for-algorithm-1})
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\label` command should always be used *after* the command that sets the counter for the element that you want to refer to. For figures, tables, and also algorithms this is the `\caption` command. Cleveref takes the name from the most recent counter update as well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,makeidx]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{center}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
code
\caption{Algorithm}\label{label-for-algorithm-1}
\end{algorithm}
\end{center}
\section{Second section}
(See \Cref{label-for-algorithm-1})
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this resolves the issue.